# Histogram from grade array list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram from an arrayList containing student grades. I have already made a grade breakdown as shown here:

```
/**
 * Returns a simple, 5-element array with the counts for each of the letter grades,
 * (A, B, C, D, and F), based on the 10-point scale
 * @return 5-element array
 */
private int[] calculateGradingBreakdown() {
    int[] breakdown;
    breakdown = new int[7];
    for (Student kids: this.students) {
        int grade = kids.getNumericGrade();
        if (grade >= 90) {
            breakdown[0] += 1;
        } else if (grade >= 80) {
            breakdown[1] += 1;
        } else if (grade >= 70) {
            breakdown[2] += 1;
        } else if (grade >= 60) {
            breakdown[3] += 1;
        } else {
            breakdown[4] += 1;
        }
    }
    return breakdown;
}

/**
 * Returns a string that lists the grade letter and the count of students
 * receiving the grade on the roster
 * @return grade breakdown
 */
public String getGradeBreakdown() {
    String gradeBreakdown = null;
    int[] breakdown = this.calculateGradingBreakdown();
    gradeBreakdown = ("A: " + breakdown[0] + "\nB: " + breakdown[1] + "\nC: " + breakdown[2]
            + "\nD: " + breakdown[3] + "\nF: " + breakdown[4]);
    return gradeBreakdown;
}
```

The code I have for the histogram has changed a few times, but needs to include the methods listed below. I have left my current code in, but am struggling as to how to get the histogram to work as listed.

```
/**
 * Accepts a number of stars (*) to be created, creates a String with that
 * number of *'s side-by-side, and then returns that string.
 */
private String makeStarRow(int number) {
    int[] breakdown = this.calculateGradingBreakdown();
    number = breakdown[];
    String stars = 
}

/**
 * Returns a string holding a horizontal histogram of *'s
 */
public String getGradeHistogram() {
    String gradeHistogram = null;
    int[] breakdown = this.calculateGradingBreakdown();
    gradeHistogram = (this.makeStarRow(breakdown[0]));
    gradeHistogram += (this.makeStarRow(breakdown[1]));
    gradeHistogram += (this.makeStarRow(breakdown[2]));
    gradeHistogram += (this.makeStarRow(breakdown[3]));
    gradeHistogram += (this.makeStarRow(breakdown[4]));

    return gradeHistogram;
}
```

The output should look like this to end for the grade breakdown and histogram (with the numbers being according to the input in another class):

```
A: 2
B: 2
C: 2
D: 0
F: 1

**
**
**

*
```

Comment: So what is the question? How to implement `makeStarRow()`? Your javadoc says it all. Just do what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your interest and reference, here's a solution using Java 8 streams:

```
void printHistogram(List<Integer> scores) {
    scores.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n < 60 ? 5 : n / 10));
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry::comparingByKey)
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue().size());
        .map(size -> Stream.iterate(() -> "*").limit(size).collect(Collectors.joining()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to create the string of repeating symbols is to use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28char[],%20char%29):

```
private String makeStarRow(int number) {
    char[] starChars = new char[number];
    Arrays.fill(starChars, '*');
    String stars = new String(starChars) + '\n';
    return stars;
}
```

Note that according to the `getGradeHistogram` method it's likely that you need a `'\n'` appended to the end of the stars String.

Comment: Why build a String from a `char[]`, then do String concatenation to add one more char? String concatenation means `new StringBuilder().append(new String(charChars)).append('\n').toString()`. *Yikes!!* Build the array one larger and set the last char to `\n`. Or two larger and set the last two to `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: @Andreas, such optimization mean nothing for the overall performance of the OP's program, but makes it much harder to maintain (replacing '\n' with something else will require patching the array length as well). Also append of single char can be [optimized](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp#l533) by JIT. Single array copying will still occur, but no StringBuilder instance with intermediate array will be actually created.

Comment: @Andreas, my benchmark show that for hot code you will save 20 ns per row of 1-10 stars and 200 ns per 100 stars row. Such premature optimization adds nothing to the application which prints these rows to the stdout. Printing (even redirected to nul) takes at least 100x more time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I actually got a working solution:

```
/**
 * Accepts a number of stars (*) to be created, creates a String with that
 * number of *'s side-by-side, and then returns that string.
 */
private String makeStarRow(int number) {
    while (number > 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
        number--;
    } 
    if (number < 1) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns a string holding a horizontal histogram of *'s
 * @return histogram
 */
public String getGradeHistogram() {
    int[] histogram = this.calculateGradingBreakdown();
    for (int xi = 0; xi < this.students.size(); xi++) {
        int meh = histogram[xi];
        this.makeStarRow(meh);
    }
    return "";
}
```

It prints out what I was looking for. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

A: 2

B: 2

C: 2

D: 0

F: 1

**

**

**

*